# Can't bind DependencyProperty to my UserControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have next problem: i have a View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock>
            test
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TestingTest}"></TextBlock>
            test
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

with code-behind:

```
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string TestingTest
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TestingTestProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestingTestProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestingTestProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TestingTest", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new UIPropertyMetadata("testing test"));

}
```

and i try to use this view in my view with ViewModel:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" Name="wnd" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:WpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <WpfApplication1:UserControl1 TestingTest="{Binding ElementName=wnd, Path=Title}"></WpfApplication1:UserControl1>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public string GoGoGo
    {
        get
        {
            return "Test message";
        }
    }
}
```

but every time i got next message in Output window and dont see test message:

**System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'TestingTest' property not found on 'object' ''UserControl1' (Name='my')'. BindingExpression:Path=TestingText; DataItem='UserControl1' (Name='my'); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
**

What do i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo.

On your UserControl you have the property `TestingTest` and on the WPF you have `TestingText` ('s' and 'x')